# Is my MVC/Web API routing correct?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this Web API call set up but seem to be having some routing problems.

```
 [HttpPut]
    public void PutTransTable(Customer customer)
    {
        if (!repository.Update(customer))
        {
            throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }            
    }
```

My WebAPIConfig is:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "inputValueAPI",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{inputValue}",
           defaults: new { areaCode = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "TestNumberAPI",
         routeTemplate: "api/Testnumber/{action}/{testnumber}",
         defaults: new { testnumber = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "IVRLookupAPI",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{LookUpType}/{LookUpValue}",
          defaults: new { areaCode = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

I'm not sure which route it will take when making the call above.
Do I need to do a special route for a Put with an object parameter rather then an int?

Comment: Do you have a Put action in the same WebAPI controller class as your PutTransTable action?

Comment: You don't need, it should work without adding additional routes. How do you test if it works? Try Postman extension for chrome, make a PUT request, show your controller and tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: The only put action in the controller is the PutTransTable action.